# ERROR undefined state: Setting state to object from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Assign state to null.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = null;
  }
```

**This is where everything goes wrong.** Select is equal to an object from an array. Why is my console telling me that setState cannot be equal to undefined?

```
  assignCompany(id) {
    this.props.companies.forEach(function(company) {
      if (company.id === id) {
        var select = [];
        select = company;
        this.setState({select});
      }
    });
  }
```

Code that is rendered.

```
  render() {
    this.assignCompany(1);
    return (
...
                  <CompanyProfile company={this.state.company} />
...
```

Comment: if `select` is already an object you dont need to wrap it in `{}` try `this.setState(select);`. Or if you're calling it like this later: `company={this.state.company}` perhaps do `this.setState({company:select});`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing differently

```
assignCompany(id) {
    this.props.companies.forEach(function(company) {
      if (company.id === id) {
        this.setState({company: company});
      }
    });
  }
```